# Disable date if selected first time in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, element

```
data() {
  return {
    datePickerOptions: {
          disabledDate(date) {
            // console.log(form.installation_date); // undefined form
            return date < this.form.ins_date ? this.form.ins_date : new Date();
          },
        },

}
```

This is saying form undefined i can understand can't initiaize form input inside data return how can i achieve this. disable other date if greater than first input date
please guide

Comment: from your fiddle, your biggest problem is the return in the datePickerOptions you have above. Data is a function so when it comes across a `return` the function ends, therefore the rest of your data is not applied. Make datePickerOptions a computed property.

Comment: I did but does not work either

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/reqg249h/ Getter is missing for computed property "datePickerOptions".

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, you can't have a function returning something in your data so you have to shift your logic somewhere else. You can put that function in your methods:

```
data() {
  return {
    datePickerOptions: {
      disabledDate: this.isDateDisabled
     },
     // rest of data
```

...

```
methods: {
  isDateDisabled(date) {
    return date < new Date(this.ruleForm.date1);
  },
```